# How to escape string interpolation in Coffeescript

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I am trying to use this section of code from jQuery UI's tabs example and convert it to Coffeescript. I've run it through the awesome http://js2coffee.org/ tool.

```
var tabTitle = $( "#tab_title" ),
    tabContent = $( "#tab_content" ),
    tabTemplate = "<li><a href='#{href}'>#{label}</a> <span class='ui-icon ui-icon-close'>Remove Tab</span></li>",
    tabCounter = 2;
```

The problem is that tabTemplate variable declaration. Coffeescript is trying to do string interpolation on it, as far as I can tell. I've tried escaping it with a slash, but that just resolves to using a slash in the converted js.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use single-quotes to delimit your string: http://coffeescript.org/#strings

If you want to use single-quotes within your string without manually escaping them you can use 3 single-quotes:

```
x = '''
my string's ok with single quotes and #{doesn't interpolate}
'''
```

That said, this is HTML, so double-quotes are actually more common for attributes than single-quotes. Your string could therefore be written as:

```
tabTemplate = '<li><a href="#{href}">#{label}</a> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-close">Remove Tab</span></li>'
```

without any problems.

Comment: Yuck. Is that the best we can do?  Why don't the double-quotes work?

Comment: Because double-quoted strings are what cause the interpolation :) That's the difference between double- and single-quoted strings. See http://coffeescript.org/#strings

Comment: Still yuck.  Is there any way to escape the entire string, like C# does with @"some\string"?

Comment: Yep, that's what the triple-single-quotes do :)

Comment: Oh. It's not at all clear from the CoffeeScript documentation that triple-single quotes (mind boggles) is the way this works. Anyway, I upvoted your answer based on your second idea.

Comment: I'm wondering: This question has been answered, but where is the solution to `$( "#tab_title" )`, brother?

Comment: Same answer... Use single quotes: `$('#tab_title')` or escape the `#` with `$("\#tab_title")`

Answer (score 8):

Escaping with backslash does work:

```
$ coffee -bce '"\#{a}"'
"\#{a}";

$ coffee -bce '"#\{a}"'
"#\{a}";
```

Comment: So, we can do:
str = " \"#{text wrapped with double quotes}\""